# using ensript to print project dir

Tags: unix, printing

I've installed enscript on my mac. But don't get it to print the complete project directory (with subdirectories). Which command would I use to print all *.as and *.mxml files including subdirs?

thx
daniel

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.as" -or -name "*.mxml" | xargs enscript -P printer
```

Where you issue this command in the top most directory you want to print.